# Android: CardView foreground using databinding

Tags: android, data-binding, android-cardview

I'm trying to fill my RecyclerView with CardViews, the CardViews use Android databinding to set Attributes like Texts in TextViews. On Items that aren't finished jet I want to add a greyish overlay. But unfortunately the  foreground `android:foreground="@{viewModel.getState != State.FINISHED? @color/gray_transparent54 : null}">` is not applied. On the other hand, if I force the foreground color `android:foreground="@grey_transparent54">`, it works it is.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data class="ListItemBinder">
        <import type="myProject.State"/>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="myProject.ListItemViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:foreground="@{viewModel.getState != State.FINISHED? @color/gray_transparent54 : null}">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{viewModel.getName}"
                tools:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/color_text_primary"
                android:textSize="24sp"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: States are Enums, the getState method exists and returns the specific State enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you've implemented getters like `getGetState()` and `getGetName()`  I think you're accessing your `viewModel` fields incorrectly. Although you didn't post your `ListItemViewModel` I suspect you need something closer to this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:foreground="@{viewModel.state != State.FINISHED? @color/gray_transparent54 : null}">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.name}"
            tools:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_primary"
            android:textSize="24sp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Data binding automatically looks for a method in your `ListItemViewModel` class named "getName()" when you access `@{viewModel.name}`, "getState()" when you access `@{viewModel.state}` etc.

Note: although UI logic is generally ok, be wary of putting business logic in your XML, as it can limit your flexibility and make testing/debugging more difficult.

Know also that you cannot mix types when using the ternary (`?:`) operator, so something like choosing between a color int and a drawable will not work. However, you can easily work around this by using custom `BindingAdapter` methods, e.g. make a binding adapter that takes your `ListItemViewModel` as a parameter, and put all your logic for what type of value to set within the method itself.

Comment: I've done terrible things using ternary operator `?:` and null coalescing `??` with mixed type data. Thus the data binding will never works